# Cocoa, output current App path

Tags: macos, cocoa, xcode4

I am working on OS X application. In the code, I would like to output a path of the current Mac OS App to a variable for future use. So later I could read the files in the same folder.  Could anyone tell me the command/method in the Xcode ?

Thanks very much.

UPDATE

To be more clear, I am using xcode and create a cocoa-application. 
My application is connected with applescript to control Mac software read files on the Mac. So I have to return the files' directory and name.

Actually I have no idea about what to do. So got stuck here.

Comment: Is this an xcode related question?

Comment: @Monolo Thanks for your attention. I think either obj-c and applescript is ok for me. It's just a simple app, is it necessary to be a NSDocument-based app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the URL of your application, you can use:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]
```

See the [NSBundle Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

my 2 cents for swift 5,x:

```
let path = Bundle.main.bundlePath
 print(path)
```

If You need a path to REAL exacutable: (i.e. you mast pass to shell or similar..)

```
 let appName =  AppName()

 let exePath = path + "/Contents/MacOS/" + appName 

  print(exePath)
```

where AppName() is:

```
func AppName()->String{
let bund = Bundle.main
//print(bund)
if let displayName = bund.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleDisplayName") as? String {
    if displayName.count>0{
        return displayName
    }
}

if let name = bund.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleName") as? String {
    return name
}
return "no AppName"
```

}